# Custom login form logo not displaying

Tags: wp-admin, wp-login-form

I'm tryng to customize the logo and the login form of a child theme I have in a wordpress site.

I've tried to use the `add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_logo')` action and inside the function I'm echoing the custom css as suggested in codex, but the desired logo will not replace the default wordpress one. How I can fix this problem?

```
function my_custom_logo(){
 ?>
  <style type="text/css">
   #login h1 a, .login h1 a {
    background-image: url('mycustomurl');
    height: 65px;
    width: 320px;
    background-size: auto;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
   }
  </style>
 <?php
}
add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_logo')
```

Comment: Your question is incomplete.  You need to include the actual function you're calling (`my_custom_logo()`) so that we have a complete picture of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @butlerblog I've uodated the question with the code. I don't know why it will be not executed and the WP logo remains the default one. The code is inside the functions.php file of my child theme.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is simply stating CSS properties, but they aren't defining anything.  They're not attached to any HTML tag, class, or ID.

Assuming your "mycustomurl" is a placeholder here for an actual URL that resolves to an image file, I would think that what you want is for these properties to be for the HTML `<a>` tag under `<h1>` in the div ID "login":

```
function my_custom_logo(){
 ?>
  <style type="text/css">
    #login h1 a {
        background-image: url('mycustomurl');
        height: 65px;
        width: 320px;
        background-size: auto;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
     }
  </style>
 <?php
}
add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_logo');
```

Comment: I've made a typo into the question code, I have my css rules pointing to this html elements `#login hi a, .login h1 a` and the rule will be not applied

Comment: You can [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/411918/edit) to correct any typos.

Comment: @PatJ edited. I've also tried with `login_head` in the functions file but seems not working also this solution. I've cleared cache but the default wp logo will be not replaced

Comment: From where are you firing the `add_action()` call to trigger this?

Comment: @butlerblog functions.php file of my child theme. As I know it's the correct way to call filters or actions?

Comment: That's an OK place to put it.  Try testing with a later priority, such as `add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_logo', 100 );`  Also, when testing, you should look at the generated HTML for the wp-login.php page to see if your CSS is being added at all. That will tell you if it's an issue of your hook not being fired or something being added after it that overrides your defined property.